# uploadify $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] empty

Tags: php, uploadify

I have a problem using uploadify, on my fupload.php the $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] is empty.

upload.js :

```
$(function() {
    $('#fichier').uploadify({  
        'swf'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '/fonctions/fupload.php', //  /uploadify/uploadify.php
        'multi'     : true,
        'auto'     : false, //files automatically upload when they are added to the queue
        'cancelImage' : '/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png', 

        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify("settings", 'formData', {'nomFichier': $('#nomFichier').val() },
                    {'isUploadify': $('#isUploadify').val() },
                    {'passphrase': $('#passphrase').val() },
                    {'motdepasse': $('#motdepasse').val() },
                    {'commentaire': $('#commentaire').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail1').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail2').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail3').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail4').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail5').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail6').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail7').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail8').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail9').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail10').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail11').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail12').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail13').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail14').val() },
                    {'mail1': $('#mail15').val() });
        },
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        },
        'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
        },
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file) {
        }
    });
});

function envoieUploadify() {
    $('#fichier').uploadify('upload','*');
}
```

I made js control in the form post et I call envoieUploadify() function and in the file fupload.php $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] empty
I do it with a small file. Is there something wrong ?

Thank !! :)

Comment: `var_dumo($_FILES);`, what does it say?

Comment: Shomz meant `var_dump($_FILES);` - slight typo.

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) is empty too

Comment: Far as I can tell, you're using `Filedata` as the filename, yet you're trying to call it using `nomFichier` probably. I understand French. So, check to see if everything matches, as well as in your HTML form. @user3429155 --- Form (PHP/POST) variables are case-sensitive. `Filedata` is not the same as `filedata` as `nomFichier` is not the same as `nomfichier` etc. should that be the case.

Comment: To add; I have tried Uploadify before and it's basically an *run out of the box* piece of code. So, whatever you changed and didn't make the appropriate changes in variable matching, will cause trouble. @user3429155 - Use a fresh unaltered copy of it, and then go over it one step at a time.

Comment: nomfichier is an imput to put a name.

Comment: As I already said, Uploadify is an *out of the box* script. Whatever you changed, make sure that everything is referenced correctly. There's nothing I can say or do, to further help you on this matter. @user3429155